# One form two submit, should I just check for $_POST boolean?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I've got a form that will be using two submit buttons to post to two different databases.

One to hold permanent information, the other so that they may save the submission and return to it at a later point in time.  Normally, I would use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` when the user hits the submit button, but since there are multiple submit buttons, would I be better off checking each button via `if($_POST["button1"]){}` and `if($_POST["button2"]){}`?

Is there a better way to do this?  I've tried attaching a `click` event via `jQuery` to do this, however, when I get to a certain point, the script actually breaks and I'm not sure why. Regardless of which submit button is pressed, the form calls the same action page.

Comment: Why not delegate the data persistence on the backend instead of making the user do it?  In other words, have one submit button and let your program logic decide what databases need to be updated.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to do that.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: can't you use separate php files to submit?

Comment: Sure.  A rough idea of what you'd need to code is here: http://pastebin.com/Xi9SKmS4

Comment: @cwscribner, thanks for that reference, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Robert No problem.  Keep in mind as you develop apps that the user is king.  Anything you can do to ease the user experience is a good thing (in this case, one button click instead of two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if($_POST["button1"]=='your-button-value'){}`

and/or

`if($_POST["button2"]=='your-other-button-value'){}`

are best option to manage/handle data while submit from same form.

I don't think you will find anything better than this.

Comment: So having php find the post values for each button is the way to go then.